# rise in prices such <as> occurred [relative pronoun?]

Tags: grammar

I have come across the following sentence : 'There is a general rise in prices such as occurred in the late 60's'. I would like to know whether the word 'as' is functioned as a conjunction or relative pronoun.

Is the word 'such' an adjective modifying the word 'prices'? if so, can i put 'such' in front of 'prices'?

One more example: 'As can be imagined, estimating the value of properties on a regular basis can be a large task' Is the word 'as' a relative pronoun or conjunction?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> There is a general rise in prices such as occurred in the late 60's

This is a run on sentence.  It should be

> There is a general rise in prices, such as occurred in the late 60's

*As* is the relative pronoun that introduces the phrase *occurred in the late 60's*.  *Such* is a pronoun whose antecedent is *rise* (or *general rise in prices*).

It's odd, but not incorrect AFAIK to actually start a new sentence with *such* though, instead of setting it off with a comma, because it's heavily dependent on a preceding sentence.

Of course, it's probably easier/more correct to just remember that *such as* is an idiom, and  is equivalent to *for example.*

> There is a general rise in prices for example as occurred in the late 60's

Still really need that comma, though.

> There is a general rise in prices, for example as occurred in the late 60's.

Comment: "*As* is the relative pronoun" <== Could you provide a grammar source for that? (I've run into people saying something like that, and I'm curious as to where they might be getting that kind of information.)

Comment: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1944058 and http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/as?s=t

Comment: Pronominal *as* is an intriguing treatment, which I will have to think about. But if we do accept it, the comma should be omitted if the relative clause is intended to bear a restrictive sense  = *just such a general rise in prices as occurred in the late 60s*.

Comment: Thank you. :) -- So the culprit seems to mostly be dictionaries. Interestingly, there is a bit on a "relative 'as'" in the 1985 Quirk et al., section 15.55, pages 1115-7, too. Though, it's my impression that the typical modern grammars nowadays probably don't consider "as" as a relative pronoun (anymore), e.g. the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *CGEL* (where many "as" uses are involved in comparative constructions where "as" is considered a preposition). Interesting.